# See-through/transparent aircraft

Tags: aircraft-design

I am a pilot who loves the aviation experience. Can we build a full see through plane using material as strong as the current materials used to build the body of an aircraft. Is there research or work being done on this?

I think that aviation should see through the glasses of adventure travel. And, we should be able to see it all as we fly. Is this possible??

Thank you for your time and excitement,
jason

Comment: This isn't possible currently. Best thing you can do if you want this experience is fly a tube frame ultralight.

Comment: Would make using the restroom on a commercial flight... awkward...

Comment: ...looking for traffic.

Comment: [Wonder Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_plane?wprov=sfla1) had a plane like that in 1942

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not using typical modern construction techniques.

You have to build a structural frame and then clad it with a non-structural skinning. This technique was widely used in the early days, although the skinning was doped fabric and not transparent.

The frame technique is still used for many ultralights and hang gliders, and some transparent films are strong enough to be used for the skinning. But these types seldom have a significant fuselage. One exception I can think of is Paul MacCready's man-powered [Gossamer Condor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCready_Gossamer_Condor) and [Gossamer Albatross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCready_Gossamer_Albatross) prize-winning man-powered aircraft, which had a fuselage nacelle slung under the wing, containing pilot Bryan Allen and the drive train.

Some helicopters such as the [Bell Sioux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_H-13_Sioux) have such large "fishbowl" cockpit glazing that it exposes all the cockpit innards. The [Edgley Optica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgley_Optica) was a prototype observation aircraft along similar lines.

Talking of cockpit glazing, some flying wings had a prone pilot with the glazing forming part of the wing leading edge. These included some of the Northrop and Horten designs.

The [Junkers G.38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_G.38) airliner accommodated some passengers in wing cabins and the glazing to these formed the wing leading edge.

So yes it can be done in principle. But materials such as plexiglass or mylar film are not really suited to such things as enclosing engines or resisting birdstrike, while strengthened glass or polycarbonate get heavy and expensive so that on most planes, only small windows are practicable.

Advanced materials such as structural glass are being increasingly used in architecture, and I have no doubt that the manufacturers and researchers will keep pushing the envelope to develop new materials and new applications. But I don't know of any research focused on airframes.

Comment: I'm surprised that you forgot to mention the Linke-Hoffman R.I [picture link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linke-Hofmann_R.I#/media/File:Linke-Hofmann_R.I_cellon_fuselage.jpg) which naively tried to cover the fuselage and tail in Cellon to make it transparent.

Comment: Certainly it's possible, since - as you yourself say - many ultralight aircraft are built this way, and use modern construction techniques.  I think the problem is that you are confusing aircraft with commercial airliners.

Answer (score 0):

As Ron Beyer has said, it is currently not possible. Research is being done to create transparent materials of great strength. So far, the cost of producing this material would far outweigh its usefulness in aviation. It is more likely that you will see the application of this technology in cars before aircraft. It’s safety would have to be well proven and documented. Plus, weight would be less of a factor in automotive engineering.

Plus, the engine and cockpit would still need to be made from non-see-through material. This would defeat the purpose of making the fuselage transparent. Your view would still be obstructed.

There are much easier ways to experience adventure aviation. Tube-frame ultralights, hanggliders, paramotors, and other currently produced aircraft would all accomplish the task of flying with an almost totally unobstructed view. Many helicopters like the Schweizer S300 would be the closest to aircraft to what you are probably looking for.